# Python PhantomJS and Proxies

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, phantomjs

```
from selenium import webdriver


proxylist = open("proxylist.txt", "r+")
proxy =  proxylist.readlines()

service_args = [
    '--proxy=ip:port',
    '--proxy-type=socks5',
    ]
```

I need to change ip:port (in line 8) with an element of the list, like proxy[18] (for example), how can i do that?

I'm stucked...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for [string concatenation](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python).

What you want to archieve is something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver


proxylist = open("proxylist.txt", "r+")
proxy =  proxylist.readlines()

service_args = [
    '--proxy='+proxy[18]+':'+proxy[19],
    '--proxy-type=socks5',
    ]
```